# MPI - indefinite send and recv

Tags: c, mpi

If I am using blocking send and recv (`MPI_send()`, `MPI_recv()`), how to make theese two operation indefinite? Like they are repeating all over again?

Sample code:

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numtasks);
MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
if(rank==0){
  rc=MPI_Send(msg,1,MPI_CHAR,1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  rc=MPI_Recv(msg,1,MPI_CHAR,1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
}else{
  rc=MPI_Recv(msg,1,MPI_CHAR,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
  rc=MPI_Send(msg,1,MPI_CHAR,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

}
```

I have tried to put before `if(rank==0) -> while(1)` and it did the job, but I see there are several sends, then several recieves and I want it like - send(0), receive(1), send(1), recieve(0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can code a ring of send-receive operations easily by using **MPI_Sendrecv**:

```
int MPI_Sendrecv(void *sendbuf, int sendcount, MPI_Datatype sendtype,
    int dest, int sendtag, void *recvbuf, int recvcount,
    MPI_Datatype recvtype, int source, int recvtag,
    MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Status *status)
```

As you can see it's only a condensed version of a MPI_Send and a MPI_Recv, but it comes handy when all the process needs either to *send* **and** *receive* something.

The following code works for **any** number of processes (you can adapt it to your needs):

### CODE UPDATE #1 (Using MPI_Sendrecv)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int size, rank, value, next, prev, sendval, recval;
    double t0, t;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    value = 5;

    if (size > 1)
    {
        next = (rank + 1)% size;
        prev = (size+rank - 1)% size;

        sendval = value + rank;

        for (;;) 
        {
            t0 = MPI_Wtime();
            MPI_Sendrecv(&sendval, 1, MPI_INT, next, 1, &recval, 1, MPI_INT, prev, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            t = MPI_Wtime();

            fprintf(stdout, "[%d of %d]: Sended %d to process %d, Received %d from process %d (MPI_SendRecv Time: %f)\n",rank, size-1, sendval, next, recval, prev, (t - t0));
        }

    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

### CODE UPDATE #2 (Using separate MPI_Send/MPI_Recv)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int size, rank, value, next, prev, sendval, recval;
    double s0, s, r, r0;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    value = 5;

    if (size > 1)
    {
        next = (rank + 1)% size;
        prev = (size+rank - 1)% size;

        sendval = value + rank;

        for (;;) 
        {
            s0 = MPI_Wtime();
            MPI_Send(&sendval, 1, MPI_INT, next, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            s = MPI_Wtime();
            fprintf(stdout, "[%d of %d]: Sended %d to process %d (MPI_Send Time: %f)\n", rank, size-1, sendval, next, s-s0);

            r0 = MPI_Wtime();
            MPI_Recv(&recval, 1, MPI_INT, prev, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            r = MPI_Wtime();
            fprintf(stdout, "[%d of %d]: Received %d from process %d (MPI_Recv Time: %f)\n", rank, size-1, recval, prev, r-r0);

        }

    }
        MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

### Running Example

```
mpicc -o sendrecv sendrecv.c
mpirun -n 2 sendrecv

[0 of 1]: Sended 5 to process 1, Received 6 from process 1 (MPI_SendRecv Time: 0.000121)
[1 of 1]: Sended 6 to process 0, Received 5 from process 0 (MPI_SendRecv Time: 0.000068)
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't get only this:if (argc != 2)
        value = 5;
    else
        value = atoi(argv[1]); I am also measuring time to to take the message to get from one process to another, do you think is possible with this hybrid, MPI_SendRecv?

Comment: And do you know, if there is also a variant of MPI_Send and MPI_recv as a signle functions?

Comment: That part is not important: it only takes a value from the command line (for example `mpirun 66 -n 2` sets `value` to 66) or set `value` to a default value of 5. Timing works fine, see my update.

Comment: @Hmyzak What do you mean by "single functions"? You want the same coding using separate MPI_Send and MPI_Recv instead of using MPI_SendRecv?

Comment: Yea, I know this is more souitable solution, but I would like to see it written in MPI_Send and MPI_Recv, if you have time. I really apprecite your help! thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to give an accurate answer to that without seeing at least the basic layout of your code. Generally, you would place the Send and Receive operations inside an infinite loop. Or, if you're hard pressed for optimal communication costs (or simply feeling adventurous), you could use [persistent Send and Receive](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node61.html#SECTION003110000000000000000).